# Align menu to responsive column structure thumbnail grid?

Tags: css, menu, grid, thumbnails, caption

I'm trying to align menu to a responsive column structure thumbnail grid and add caption on hover with only css, but not successful maybe someone can help me?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/foroloca/kwyL2m11/)

```
<header>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>   
</nav>
</header>

<div id="content">
<div class="col-25"><a class="thumb" href="#"><img src="http://fakeimg.pl/500x310/999/"><div class="caption">Title  untitled</div></a></div>
```

Comment: No one can help me with this must be easy for a experienced coder?

Answer (score 0):

Add This Media query...

```
@media all and (max-width: 400px) and (min-width: 0px) {

        header {
            margin: 0 30px;
        }

        #content {
            margin-left: 20px;
            margin-right: 20px;
        }

        .col-25 {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }

    ul {
        width: 100% !important;
    }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, but i mean to align the menu to the first thumbnail 25% and only 100% when media query is 400px etc, but that already works for me.

Comment: If you want to keep the width same as in demo ..in full width then add this extra media query...

Comment: nav ul, nav ul ul {
    width: 25% !important;
}

Comment: @media (min-width:400px){
              nav ul, nav ul ul
            {

                width:25% !important;
            }
        }

Comment: replace with old one @media(min-width:400px)

Comment: No not working, but i think that i explained it not properly what i did now it almost is what i want only the menu on the right doesn't align to the first thumbnail 15px off only when in mobile screen size it works fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69212/discussion-between-foroloca-and-milind-rajput).